# Stopping Test Run in C# WinAppDriver UI Tests on Test Failure

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, winappdriver

I'm facing an issue with my solution and need assistance. Specifically, I'm trying to make the VS2022 Test Explorer stop its run when any of the tests fail.

I have attempted the following code:

```
 public static void TearDown(TestContext context)
   {
     if (context.CurrentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
       {
         session.Close();
         session = null;
       }
        }
```

And then in the `[TestCleanup]` method:

```
[TestCleanup]
  public void TestCleanup()
    {
      TestContext context = null;
      TearDown(context);
      session.Close();
      session = null;
    }
```

However, this approach did not work as expected.

Please help ;)

Comment: This is something controlled by Visual Studio, not the unit test framework or Selenium. Not sure if this will answer your question, but consider writing a [.runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file). I wonder if it gives you this level of control?